# What url can be used to implement Http server for new GCM framework

Tags: php, android, curl, google-cloud-messaging

I have implementing GCM for sending messages in my project, it works fine until 28th of july and suddenly, the Application start developing issues. my code sample for sending messages from my php App server looks like

```
 function setPush_Notification($device_Ids, $message) {
$url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";
$GOOGLE_API_KEY = "MY_API_KEY";
$fields = array('registration_ids' => $device_Ids,
    'data' => $message,
);
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . $GOOGLE_API_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$ch = curl_init();
// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

But recently, am unable to send messages and it appears the problem is from the url as every attempt returns the error :

> Failed to connect to 2a00:1450:4016:804::200a: 
>   Network is unreachable
>   And i from my findings it's the server https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send that is unreachable, what url is now used to send messages from thirdparty app servers to GCM ????.

I have tried others url https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send with no success.
has anyone else experienced this ? Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below link i have implemented GCM using this in my application 2 days back. Its working Check this out https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

```
function px_sendGCM($message, $type) {

$result;

$options = get_option('gcm_setting');

$apiKey = $options['api-key'];

$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

$id = px_getIds();



if($id >= 1000){

    $newId = array_chunk($id, 1000);

    foreach ($newId as $inner_id) {

        $fields = array(

            'registration_ids' => $inner_id,

            'data' => array( $type => $message ),);

        $headers = array(

            'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,

            'Content-Type: application/json');



        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

    }

}else {

    $fields = array(

        'registration_ids' => $id,

        'data' => array( $type => $message ),);

    $headers = array(

        'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,

        'Content-Type: application/json');



    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

}



$answer = json_decode($result);
```

Comment: My problem is not implementing the mobile client, its about the third party app server for sending downstream messages .. specifically how did you implement sending message to gcm server from your app server ? what url did you use to post data to gcm ? is it this https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send ? Could you please post a snippet of your code ??

Comment: Thanks Nikhil, both urls https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send and https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send still works as expected, I think the problem was with some firewall issues with my server host, i migrated the application to a different host and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This one is the right URL, according to https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http

```
https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

If it doesn't work too, check your network.